# How to get "X8" hex type split to "X2-X2-X2-X2" type

Tags: c#

Here is my code and I was just wondering how to split the 4bytes to 1byte-1byte-1byte-1byte

```
 static int count;
    private void SetClock_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        count++;

        label5.Text = count.ToString("X8");

        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        txtSend.Text = "4D-" + "1A-" + "2B-" + "3C-" +
        (label5.Text.ToString()) + "-" + "03-" + "07-" + "00-" + 
        time.ToString("yy-MM-dd-") +
        ((int)time.DayOfWeek).ToString("00") +
        time.ToString("-HH-mm-ss");



        string[] allHaxValues = txtSend.Text.Split(new char[] { '-' });
        int result = 0;
        foreach (string haxValue in allHaxValues)
        {
            result = result ^ Convert.ToInt32(haxValue, 16);
        }
        //txtSend.Text = s;
        txtSend.Text = txtSend.Text + ("-") + result.ToString("X2");
     }
```

I am receiving value on click "00000001". I want to get it like others "00-00-00-01" Thanks

Comment: 7 similar questions and you still can't solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `BitConverter` class to turn the `int` value into the `xx-xx-xx-xx` form:

```
// make a four byte array of the int
byte[] parts = BitConverter.GetBytes(result);
// put the bytes in the right order
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) {
  Array.Reverse(parts);
}
// turn the bytes into the xx-xx-xx-xx format
string resultString = BitConverter.ToString(parts);
```

Comment: can you type the whole code from the start. I can't understand where to use those all. Thanks

Comment: @NikolaObretenov: I'm not sure where you want to use it in your code. The code just takes an `int` value and turns it into a string in the format `xx-xx-xx-xx`. Use whichever value you want as input and use the resulting string where you want to display it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Guffa solution:

```
private string IntToBytes(int count)
{ 
// make a four byte array of the int
byte[] parts = BitConverter.GetBytes(count);
// put the bytes in the right order
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) {
  Array.Reverse(parts);
}
// turn the bytes into the xx-xx-xx-xx format
return BitConverter.ToString(parts);
}
```

now just replace

```
label5.Text = count.ToString("X8");
```

with

```
label5.Text = IntToBytes(count);
```